# NSPredicate to get Array containing specific key value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

Get all elements of array using item-"apple"

My input

```
item_list: [
    {
        CurrentDate = “4/2/2016";
        search_item =(             
            item_name = @“apple”;
        );
    },
    {
        CurrentDate = “27/1/2016";
        search_item =(
            item_name = @“Ball”;   
        );
    },
    {
        CurrentDate = “17/2/2016";
        search_item =(
            item_name = @“Cat”; 
        );
    },
    {
        CurrentDate = “6/2/2016";
        search_item =(
            item_name = @“apple”;
        );
    },
]
```

Output i need

```
item_list: [
    {
        CurrentDate = “4/2/2016";
        search_item =(             
            item_name = @“apple”;
        );
    },
    {
        CurrentDate = “6/2/2016";
        search_item =(
            item_name = @“apple”;
        );
    },
]
```

Code i try but not working

```
NSArray*  filtered = [[item_list valueForKey:@"search_item"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(item_name == %@)", @“apple”]];
```

Comment: share the resulting output of the command you tried, please

Comment: anyway I see you have sometimes "search_item" and sometimes "pTask", but you are looking for only with the first

Comment: Please add the output you get.

Comment: Is there only one search item per item or can be there more than one?

Comment: @iphonemaclover    search_item =(
            item_name = @“apple”;   );  how you store this ? array with key value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSPredicate *predicate =
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY search_item.item_name CONTAINS[c] %@", @"apple"];  
NSArray *array =[item_list filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `NSPredicate's` `predicateWithBlock:` instead of `predicateWithFormat:` I don't know how they compare performance-wise, but I find using a block much easier to work with.

Here's an example:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id  _Nonnull evaluatedObject, NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nullable bindings) {
    return [(NSDictionary *)evaluatedObject[@"search_item"][@"item_name"] isEqualToString:@"apple"];
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Predicate` is right just put your string between `single quote`

```
NSArray*  filtered = [item_listArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Any search_item.item_name = '%@'", @“apple”]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following ...

```
NSPredicate *predicate =
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY self.isFree CONTAINS[c] %@", @"YES"]; 
NSArray *array =[item_list filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```